# The accordion opens when you click on the link

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, accordion

For a long time I suffer with an accordion I can’t make it open.

I need the accordion to open when you click on the link. How to do this in my example? I found a lot of different solutions to the problem on your site, but not one of the options could apply. The accordion is at the bottom of the page.

http://elementor.echotag.net

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You use Bootstrap for this.

There are some predefined classes in bootstrap that you can use,

read more about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">
            Point 1
          </div>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Your Description for point 1
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          Footer text goes here for point 1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse2">
            Point 2
          </div>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Your Description for point 2
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          Footer text goes here for point 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the end, you do some styling as you want it, like when hovered on-points show cursor pointer, show animations if you want, or color changes, keep font size according to your needs.

**

> **NOTE:**
>
> I did not open the link provided, because it's not secure.
>
> my code here explains how to add `accordian` styles in your pages. hope this helps you.

**

Comment: Awesome option! But I would like the accordion to open when I click, for example, on any link in the menu, then in this case how will it look?

Comment: thank you niranjan harpale, can I contact you via social networks?

Comment: my answer was helpful to you? Did it solve your problem? Do you have any other questions?

Comment: if you want any or all accordion to be open by default then just change the class from class="panel-collapse collapse" to class="panel-collapse collapse in".

Comment: Thank you for your accordion niranjan, but I need to apply this effect on my accordion. can you help? how to apply this effect on my accordion that I have on the site? I'm trying to find a solution using javascript codes but I don’t know how to do it right